# Can anyone explain the mathematical, geometric or physical meaning of $(-1)^{1/3}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Suddenly, I was very confused on the mathematical or geometric meaning about cube root of a minus real number, say
$(-1)^{1/3}$. In my opinion, I think $(-1)^{1/3}=-1$, because $(-1)^3=(-1).(-1).(-1)=-1$. But when I ask Mathematica with

```
N[(-1)^(1/3)]
```

I got

```
(*0.5 + 0.866025 I*)
```

If the number is somewhat more complicated, say $\left(-\frac{27}{40}\right)^{1/3}$, how do I consider its sign, could it be considered as a *positive* number?
Or there is no plus or minus characteristic for this kind of number? Can I regard the cube root of a minus number as a minus one?

Sorry, if my question is too silly, kindly teach me. Thanks!

Comment: When you ask for $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ you actually want " a complex number $z$ such that $z^3=-1$". Clearly $z:=-1$ is okay by what you have written. Anyway, Mathematica is also right (check that the solution $s$ it gave you also verify $s^3=-1$)... Actually it is not really a big deal to show that $z^3+1=0$ will have exactly $3$ solutions and each of them is a legitimate value for $(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$... Of course it seems that $-1$ is the "best" since it is real and other solutions are not, but technically, it is correct...

Comment: It seems that Mathematice introduce **CubeRoot[x]** which gives the real-valued cube root of $x$ (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CubeRoot.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In complex numbers every number, not equal to zero, has n, n-th roots. All distinct.  The three cube roots of -1 are: $-1, 1/2 + \sqrt{3}/2 i, 1/2 - \sqrt{3}/2 i$.

So there is room for ambiguity in *which* of these should be $(-1)^{1/3}$.   In general for $b >0$ $b^{1/3}$ is defined to be the specific and unique positive root which always exist and of which there is always only one.  But if $b$ is not a positive real (or zero) then there isn't  any positive real root. There is some, but not universal, consensus as to which of the n-th roots will get the honor of being defined $b^{1/n}$.  (Others will correct me if I am wrong.)

Now one thing about n-th complex roots of $b$.  There are always n of them and they  always are positioned on the complex plane so that they are inscribed in a circle around the origin, 0, with radius $\sqrt[n]{|w|}$ and each equal angles apart.

So if there *is* a convention.  It is usually to be the first one, one encounters on the circle when looking in a counter clockwise direction starting from the real axis.  That way if $b$ is positive real the first we'd encounter is the real root.

If we follow this convention then the first 3rd root of -1 that we encounter is $1/2 + \sqrt{3}/2 i$.  So that is why mathematica gave you what it did. (*0.5 + 0.866025 I*) is *one* cube root and it is the first one, one comes to in a counter-clockwise direction.

====  more advanced  (slightly) =====

If we look at a complex number $a + b i$ in the complex plane, we can view it as an ordered pair.  It is the point that is $a$ over on the x (real)  axis and $b$ up on the y (imaginary) axis.

But we can also not that if we view it as a ray or vector form the origin, 0, we can see it has a length $r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and it has an angle $\theta$ measured from the real axis.

So we can alternatively view the complex number as $r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.  It's the same number as $a = r\cos \theta$ and $b = r\sin \theta$.  But we are viewing it, instead of a rectangular coordinated point, we are iewing it as polar coordinated point.

There is a surprising benefit to viewing it this way:

If we let $w = e^{\ln r}(cos \theta + i sin \theta)$ is one complex number and $z = e^{\ln t}(cos \phi + i sin \phi)$ is another then $wz = e^{\ln r + \ln t}([\cos \theta \cos \phi - sin \theta \sin phi] + i [ cos \theta \sin \phi + \cos \phi \sin \theta]) = e^{\ln r + \ln t}(\cos (\theta + \phi) + i \sin (\theta + \phi))$.

In other words we found a way to do multiplication but adding the angles and multiplying the lengths.

(We go a step further and define and write  $e^{a + b i} = e^a(\cos b + i \sin b)$ but we won't today.)

So anyway.  This means:  To find the n-th roots of $a + bi$ you convert it to $r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.  Then... wait for it... the n-th roots will be: ${r^{1/n}(\cos (\theta/n + 2k\pi/n) + i \sin (\theta/n + 2k\pi/n)} $ for $k = 0, 1, ..., n-1$. (as raising those to the $n$th power will result in $({r^{1/n}}^n(\cos (n\theta/n + 2kn\pi/n)  + i \sin (n\theta/n + 2kn\pi/n)=  r(\cos(\theta + 2k\pi) + i \sin (\theta + 2k\pi)) = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$.)

Which is why the convention is the define *the* default i-th root by the formula above with k = 0.

So if $-1 = 1(cos \pi + i \sin \pi)$ then $-1^{1/3} = 1^{1/3}(\cos \pi/3 + i \sin \pi/3) = 1/2 + \sqrt{3}/2 i$.

But the other two are $(\cos (\pi/3 + 2\pi/3) + i \sin (\pi/3 + 2\pi/3)) = \cos \pi + i \sin \pi = -1$

And $\cos (\pi/3 + 4\pi/3) + i \sin (\pi/3 + 4\pi/3) = \cos -\pi/3 + i \sin -\pi/3 = 1/2 - \sqrt{3}/2 i$.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, we do algebra in the real numbers ( $\mathbb{R}$), but here you're looking at a different set. You are getting different answers because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed. Namely, the **degree** of a polynomial corresponds to its number of **roots**. Interestingly enough, this is not the case in the real numbers ( take $x^{2}+1=0$ for example, which is solving for the roots of a parabola that does not intersect the x-axis.) In other words:

$$(-1)^3=-1.$$

However, $e^{i \pi/3}$ and $e^{-i\pi/3}$ are also legitimate solutions in the complex numbers.

This is true because $e^{i \pi/3}=\cos(\pi/3)+i\cdot \sin(\pi/3)\approx .5+i\cdot.86603$

This is a solution because $(e^{i \pi/3})^{3}=e^{i \pi}=-1$.

Hence the famous equation: $e^{i \cdot \pi}+1=0$.

This is part of what makes mathematics in the complex numbers so well-behaved.

Comment: If you'd like to investigate this idea further, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Hi, @ Andres Mejia, thanks for your rapid answer. Now I understood a bit. Two question: 1. What is your mean by C, (Sorry, I don't know how to type it), could u pls tell me how to do it. 2. Pls check my update.

Comment: $\mathbb C$ simply means the set of complex numbers.  $\mathbb N$ = the Natural numbers $\subset \mathbb Z$ = the Integers $\subset \mathbb Q$ = the Rational numbers $\subset \mathbb R$ = the Real numbers $\subset \mathbb C$ = the Complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, $(-1)^3=-1$, hence $-1=(-1)^{1/3}$.

Anyway, there are two other solutions in complex numbers, $\dfrac{1\pm i\sqrt3}2$. Indeed,

$$\left(\frac{1\pm i\sqrt3}2\right)^3=\frac{1\pm i3\sqrt3-3\left(\sqrt3\right)^2\mp i\left(\sqrt3\right)^3}8=-1.$$

Mathematica prefers one of these.

---

**Interpretation**:

In the reals, multiplying by $-1$ is a mirroring around the origin. Three mirrorings amount to a single one.

In the complex, numbers are represented by points in a plane, and multiplying by a complex number is the combination of a rotation and a scaling, around the origin.

The two complex solutions correspond to rotations of $\pm60°$, with unit scaling. Hence three rotations are equivalent to a single one by $\pm180°$, i.e. multiplication by $-1$.

Comment: Nice explanation! @ Yves Daoust, I am also like your answer, but I can not accept more than one :)